# Why Range.Interior.Pattern = xlNone property also changes the fill color to none?

Tags: excel, vba

I think the title is enough. Any ideas? Is this a bug? Yes - both properties are about the Interior of the range, but fill color and pattern should be separated in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In testing, using `xlPatternAutomatic`, instead of `xlNone` (or `xlPatternNone`), retains the interior color.